# Nested Case for hard coding result of a case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset similar to this;

```
col1 col2 col3
1     YES  NO
2     NO   YES
```

I am trying to apply `case` statement,

```
case when col1 = 1 then col2
     when col1 = 2 then col3 end as newcol
```

Now the `newcol` will have values as `YES/NO` in the output. Is it possible to apply another `case` inside the above `case` condition, So that I can hardcode `YES` as `Y` and `NO` as `N`.

I have got the result by adding a `case` statement in the an outer query. Is there any alternate approach like nested `case`.

Also can I apply `case` condition using the column alias `newcol`?

Comment: I don't follow you.  Can you add sample data showing what you mean?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen After taking the result of the `case` statement, I wish to add another `case` to make `YES` as `Y` and `NO` as `N`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a case expression around your `case`, like this:

```
case (
    case
        when col1 = 1 then col2
        when col1 = 2 then col3
    end
) when 'YES' then 'Y' else 'N' end as newcol
```

`SUBSTR` would pick the first character of `YES` or `NO` without a conditional:

```
SUBSTR(
    case
        when col1 = 1 then col2
        when col1 = 2 then col3
    end
,   1
,   1
) as newcol
```